# Basis for photo panorama stitching

Tags: sequences-and-series, differential-geometry, transformation, plane-geometry

What nice basis sets are there for the space of invertible transformations in $\mathbb R^2$?

Say I have a manifold $\mathcal M$ (in fact it is either the Euclidean plane $\mathbb R^2$ or the sphere $S^2$), and two different coordinate charts $\varphi:U_\varphi \rightarrow\mathbb R^2$ and $\psi:U_\psi\rightarrow\mathbb R^2 $ where $U_\varphi,U_\psi\subset \mathcal M$ (moreover let these charts each map to some rectangle $\mathbb I\subset \mathbb R^2$ in coordinate space). Furthermore, let the image of these two charts overlap in some region $U_\varphi \cap U_\psi$ (which happens to be a strict subset of $U_\varphi$ and of $U_\psi$). The transformation $\varphi \circ \psi^{-1}$ thus is an invertible function which maps $\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow\mathbb R^2$ (albeit only defined for some bounded domain and range).

I'd like a basis series, i.e. let $\varphi \circ \psi^{-1} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum^n_i w_i\, f_i$ where $\left\{ f_i:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2 \right\}$, such that the transformation map can be *approximated* with a (small) finite number of terms. Perhaps something resembling a cosine expansion or spherical harmonics (enabling separation of fast-varying components). Ideally, I'd prefer the basis expansion to have some kind of symmetry with respect to its inverse, such as for any given $n$, that $\sum^n_i w_i\, f_i = \left( \sum^n_i w'_i\, f_i \right)^{-1}$.

An application for this is that the manifold is a (potential) panoramic image scene, each photo is a chart, and by automatic feature matching (such as the SIFT computer vision algorithm) for each overlapping pair of photos I have a large number of points $x$ for which I already know both $\varphi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$. I want to interpolate *and extrapolate* these datapoints (e.g. analytically approximate $\varphi \circ \psi^{-1}$ and then smoothly *extend* it) in order to align and stitch the photos together. The simplest ways to do this would be to start by choosing one master image (e.g. only consider $\varphi \circ \psi^{-1}$ not $\psi \circ \varphi^{-1}$) or incorporate special knowledge about the camera lens function $\varphi_{(\Theta,\Phi)}$. However, I want to avoid brittle assumptions about the cameras, and I also want to avoid treating any one photo as more privileged than the others (so that I can instead try to average out their peculiar view geometries).

Comment: Do you understand [this](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/video-lectures/lecture-31-change-of-basis-image-compression/) stuff?

Comment: You say you want to avoid brittle assumptions about cameras. But I think successful engineering of this kind of thing _does_ require some statistics about real-world data. For example compressing a video of a lecturer at a chalkboard—you can use less data by assuming that most of the pixels will not change from frame to frame.

Comment: What I mean @isomorphismes is that I do not know the focal length of the lens and the size of the sensor (e.g. whether it is a fisheye lens or a pinhole camera). Perhaps one of my photos is a crop (rather than the full natural frame of the camera lens) and conversely perhaps one is already the result of stitching a sub-panorama together. You're right that this still is amenable to many good simplifying approximations, particularly regards slow directional variation of the lens function.